# Pre-populate Django form ChoiceField with instance data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Help needed with pre-populating Django forms: I have a form that updates a UserProfile model, when the form is loaded I want it pre-populated with the existing UserProfile data. Simple enough, the instance can be passed to the form. However, it seems that fields with choices (which come out as `select` drop-down elements in HTML) are not pre-populated with the instance data and instead default to '-----------'.

I've tried manually setting the initial value for a specific form (e.g. country) but it doesn't pull through to the HTML.

```py
    form = UserProfileForm(instance=user_profile)
    form.fields['country'].initial = 'GBR'
```

I'm sure I could create a convoluted work around to get the current country selected in the front-end but it feels like it should be possible in Django. I couldn't see any solutions in other questions.

Comment: Can you please share the model for which you made a form?

Comment: The model is just a FK to the user, a few CharFields and the Country field (only that has a choice and all the others work correctly)

Comment: well the way `choices` is structured is important. So can you at least share that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [dynamically set default for a form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) as:

```
form = UserProfileForm(instance=user_profile, initial={'country': 'GBR'})
```

If `country` field should be populated from `user_profile` data, then you can define form as following (assuming `country` is a field in `UserProfile` class)

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.initial['country'] = instance.country
```

**Why what you are doing isn't working?**

You are using:

```
form.fields['country'].initial = 'GBR'
```

This will not work on for [a bounded form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms). `form = UserProfileForm(instance=user_profile)` will return a bounded form.

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#initial):

> The `initial` argument lets you specify the initial value to use when rendering this `Field` in an **unbound** `Form`.
>
> To specify dynamic initial data, see the [`Form.initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial) parameter.

Comment: That sets the default to always be ‘GBR’ and doesn’t dynamically take the instance field value

Comment: Then use `initial={'country': somevariable }` to set it.

Comment: That’s the same approach as in the question but it doesn’t change the output - the ‘somevariable’ isn’t selected

Comment: No, it's not same. You are doing `self.fields['country'].initial = somevariable`. You should do `self.initial['country'] = somevariable`. You need to populate [`Form.initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial).

Comment: You're right, I should say that neither `initial={'country':'GBR'}` or `self.fields['country'].initial = somevariable` work as hoped - using `self.initial['country'] = somevariable` does though, thank you!